# In Word 2010 what causes the highlighting menu's No Color option to have a coloured box?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

In Microsoft Word 2010 on the highlighting menu sometimes the No Color option has a coloured box next to it.

Does anyone know what this signifies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just to show that "No Color" is the currently selected choice.

If I highlight some text in red and then open the highlighting menu, you'll see that the box next to "No Color" is blank:

[image: Highlighted]

If I remove the highlighting, you can see that the box next to "No Color" has some slight colouring - it's just to represent that it is selected.

[image: Not highlighted]

Comment: Yes I see. I also notice in your first screen shot that the red box has a border around it to show that it is the current choice.